# Django Admin - SubModels on Parent Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Django model called `Product`. I want to add a 1:n relation in `Product` to choose the images of it product, and on the `Product` Admin form i want that user add the images.

I tried `ManyToMany` relation but it's not exactly what i want because I don't want that the user visit two forms `Product` to create products, `Images` to create the images and then `Products` again to select the images of that `Product` will have.

Anyone has an ideia? Sorry if i am not clear, and let me know if you need more informations.

**models.py**:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    """ Generic image model
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, verbose_name=_("name")) 
    image_file = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=image_upload, verbose_name=_("file"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.name)

    def post_url(self):
        return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images', self.__class__.__name__)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name=_("Image")
        verbose_name_plural=_("Images")

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name=_("name"))
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, db_index=True, verbose_name=_("date"))
    cover_image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=product_cover_upload,verbose_name=_("image"))
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True,verbose_name=_("category"))
    value = models.DecimalField(blank=False, max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,verbose_name=_("value"))
    featured = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False,verbose_name=_("featured"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name=_("product")
        verbose_name_plural=_("products")

class ProductImage(Image):
    """ Product images
    """
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,verbose_name=_("product"))

    def post_url(self):
        return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images', 'products', str(self.product))

    class Meta:
        proxy = False
        verbose_name=_("product image")
        verbose_name_plural=_("products images")
```

**admin.py**:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'creation_date', 'category', 'value', 'featured',)
    read_only_fields = ('creation_date',)

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: @AlexKarahanidi added the `models.py` and `admin.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

admin.py:

```
class ProductImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProductImage


class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductImageInline]
```

Comment: Thanks, it was what i looking for